# [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000113'

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uicollectionview

I am trying to display images in `collectionView`. Getting data from server with 17 images. I took an `Array` called `Imageofarray`. I am appending 17 images to `array`. when I am going to display in `collectionView`, its showing below exception:

> unrecognized selector sent to an instance

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProudpartnersViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"
                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    myCell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    myCell.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    myCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 3.0);
    myCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    NSString *strImg_Path = [[NSString alloc]init];

    NSString *arrayResult = [imageOfArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // error is here
    strImg_Path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSURL URLWithString:arrayResult]];
    [myCell.proudOfImages sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImg_Path]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholer_image"]];    
    return myCell;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Show your array.

Comment: Your app was crashing due to 'type cast' issue. Check the type of [imageOfArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]. which type of object it is in index of array.

Comment: can you check my array (
    17,
        {
        sponsorImage = "http://13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/pega.jpg";
    },
        {
        sponsorImage = "http://13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/yogabar.jpg";
    },
        {
        sponsorImage = "http://13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/cykul.png";
    },
        {
        sponsorImage = "http://13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/tsiic.png";
    },

Comment: Your array's first index object is an Integer (17) and you are trying to type cast into String.

Comment: are you seen this , your 0th index is number `17` , before refresh the data remove this and use

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but there are two lines of redundant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove 0th Index integer make array as follows

```
imageOfArray = ({ sponsorImage = "13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/pega.jpg";; }, { sponsorImage = "13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/yogabar.jpg";; }, { sponsorImage = "13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/cykul.png";; }, { sponsorImage = "13.126.20.47/app/cykulpelotons/sponsors/images/tsiic.png";; })
```